# how to retrieve the class from pagemethod in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to use Pagemethod to return the class to javascript. Does it need to create the same construction of the class on the both sides, client and server sides?

Comment: I think we need some more information. What is _"the class"_? How are you returning it? JSON? Some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I use the following code on vb.net

```
  <WebMethod()> _
      Public Shared Function checkTime(ByVal ID As Integer) As Integer()

      Do something and return the value
      End Function
```

On javascript calling the method:

```
 PageMethods.checkTime(ID, OncheckTimeComplete, OncheckTimeError, senderInfo);
```